# Targeting the first class instance on a page with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a bunch of divs with the class of showreel and I'd like the first one to have a higher margin value. I'm trying to achieve this using CSS advanced selectors but can't seem to figure it out.

I know that you can target native elements like 
    p:first-child
but can I use it for div classes e.g. 
    .showreel:first

Looked around quite a bit but I just find information on native elements. Any help appreciated, but would rather have a CSS solution vs. a JS solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question: are you really just looking for every first-child that also has the class applied, or are you (as I inferred) looking for exactly the first instance of the class in the entire document, whether or not it happens to be the first child of a parent element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No such functionality exists in CSS. You will need to use a JS solution to find them on the client machine, or a server-side solution to apply an additional class to the first element with this CSS class. Which to use depends on how important it is to style this item uniquely.

Using jQuery, you could find the first instance of the class via:

```js
var firstAsJQueryObject = $('.showreel').eq(0);
var firstAsDOMElement   = $('.showreel')[0];
```

Using pure JavaScript on modern browsers:

```js
var firstAsDOMElement = document.querySelector('.showReel');
```

Using pure JavaScript on older browsers:

```js
function findFirstElementWithClass(className){
  var hasClass = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+className+"(?:\\s|$)");
  for (var all=document.getElementsByTagName('*'),len=all.length,i=0;i<len;++i){
    if (hasClass.test(all[i].className)) return all[i];        
  }
}
var firstAsDOMElement = findFirstElementWithClass('showReel');
```

If you are going to use JavaScript, instead of applying the visual style through JavaScript I would suggest apply a class using JavaScript and still using CSS to style the element:

```js
// Using jQuery for simplicity
$('.showreel').eq(0).addClass('first-showreel');
```

```css
.first-showreel {
  /* apply your presentation here */
}
```

---

**Edit**: Note that the much-higher-voted answer by @mickey_roy is **incorrect**. It will only work when the element with the class you want is also the first element of its type on the page.

Writing `.showreel:nth-of-type(1)` means, *"Find me the first element with each class name that also has the `showreel` class applied."* If the same element type appears earlier on the page without the class, it will fail. If a different element type shares the same class, it will fail.

The question asks how to select the first instance of the class. See below for an example of how very wrong that answer is for this question.

```css
div { color:red }
.showreel:nth-of-type(1) {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:green
}
```

```html
<div>not this</div>
<div class="showreel">this should be green</div>
<div>not this</div>
<div class="showreel">not this</div>
<p class="showreel">not this</p>
<section class="showreel">not this</section>
```

Comment: @KeokiZee Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but I'm pretty sure that `first-child` is not a solution to the question. As [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTEaz/1/), it certainly does not help you "select the first class instance".

Comment: Right, a CSS first-child wouldn't work in the case you linked to because the pseudo class works relative to it's parent, not the page. If that was the intent of the question (first instance on the page), your solution is perfect.

Comment: my apologies, it appears that I have indeed misunderstood the question, you are right, your solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 33):

I used [this article from CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/) to select the first instance of a class, not its child.  It worked brilliantly for me!  No extra HTML or JS required.

```
.title:nth-of-type(1){
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I almost upvoted this but it's no good in IE8.  I know we all want the web to move forward but IE8 is still widely used and will continue to make our lives difficult for years to come.

Comment: This answer is useful, but I don't think it should be the accepted answer because it won't answer the case where the number of preceeding div elements without the targetted class is not known. e.g. `<div><div><div class="showreel">` requires updating to `nth-of-type(2)`, and so on.

Comment: @fazy - But the OP stated that the targetted class *is* known. Therefore, it is a perfectly acceptable solution, and should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Leave the JS out of this and just display the unstyled version for IE8 and below.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See the edit to my answer for why. Using `nth-of-type` may be an acceptable workaround for specific cases that have additional restrictions beyond what the question asked requires.

Comment: This answer is not correct. It will work if only .title is also the first of its type (div, p, h1, span, whatever) in the document. So when it seems to work it's by chance.